# Compile error: Can't assign to array in VBA function that reutrns array dictionary objects)

Tags: vba

I have the following code:

```
Function MC() As Object()

Dim RulesList(0 To 10) As Object

Dim Rule
Set Rule = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Rule.Add "Sender", "Test"
Rule.Add "Subject", "bbb"
Rule.Add "Folder", "ccc"
Rule.Add "MarkRead", False

Set RulesList(0) = Rule


Set Rule = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Rule.Add "Sender", "Java"
Rule.Add "Subject", "bbb"
Rule.Add "Folder", "ccc"
Rule.Add "MarkRead", False

Set RulesList(1) = Rule

Set MC = RulesList

End Function
```

in outlook VBA.
The code throws

> "Compile Error: Can't assign to array on line Set MC = RulesList

Can somebody help me here please? I want to create an array of dictionary objects and return them.

EDIT: Removing () at the end of function signature and using MC = RulesList in place of Set MC = RulesList works, however, I can't assign this in my calling function anymore, can anyone point me to help on that?

Comment: VBA is driving me nuts :( Can I also get the code that I should write to store the return value please, I'll do

Dim T As Object<br>

MsgBox( T( 0 )( "Sender" ) )

Comment: Perhaps this might be somehow helpful: http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805566489990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL.DEV&Version=12&CTT=4&origin=EC001022991

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

```
Function MC() As Object()
    Dim RulesList(0 To 10) As Object

    Set Rule = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Rule.Add "Sender", "Test"
    Rule.Add "Subject", "bbb"
    Rule.Add "Folder", "ccc"
    Rule.Add "MarkRead", False

    Set RulesList(0) = Rule


    Set Rule = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Rule.Add "Sender", "Java"
    Rule.Add "Subject", "bbb"
    Rule.Add "Folder", "ccc"
    Rule.Add "MarkRead", False
    Debug.Print Rule(1)

    Set RulesList(1) = Rule

    MC = RulesList

End Function

Sub getmc()
    Dim abc
    abc = MC
    Set Rule = abc(1)
    a = Rule.items
    Debug.Print a(0)
End Sub
```